# Insert User Email into Form Automatically jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to grab text generated by javascript and paste it into a forms input value field. This is what I have so far:

```
var txt=$('#grabemail').text();
$('#email').val(unescape(txt));

<p id="grabemail" style="color:#fff;">
  <script type="text/javascript">formData.display("email")</script>
</p>
```

The only problem is that when the jQuery grabs the text from #grabemail it not only takes the email but it also takes 'formData.display' so I end up with:

formData.display("email")user@email.com

In the field as opposed to just the email.

I cannot edit the JS inside of the #grabemail div.

Anybody have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Could you just get the substring?

Comment: What is formData? Can you read values directly from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var txt = unescape($('#grabemail').text());
$('#email').val(txt.replace('formData.display("email")',''));
```

have you tried this way?

Answer (score 1):

```
txt=txt.substring(25, txt.length);
```

This should work.